# jenv can't find java 17 installed through the brew on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, homebrew, java-17, jenv

I'm trying to install JDK 17 to macOS BigSur (11.5.2) using `brew install openjdk@17`

```sh
> brew install openjdk@17
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 3 formulae.

openjdk  is already installed but outdated (so it will be upgraded).
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/manifests/17.0.1_1
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/blobs/sha256:75ee17c1331022fa8bf1e63f00fe903f23fe31d3a09021117d46b5f6ed1e26e1
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:75ee17c1331022fa8bf1e63f00fe903f23fe31d3a09021117d46b5f6ed1e26e1?se=2021-12-09T20%3A25%3A00Z&sig=NnB%2FO%2BGQF5ec6iqdKA4w29
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring openjdk--17.0.1_1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
  sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk

openjdk is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides similar software and installing this software in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have openjdk first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openjdk you may need to set:
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include"
```

After installation `jenv` can't find the instance of java17

```sh
jenv versions                                                                                                                               
  system
  1.8
  1.8.0.161
  1.8.0.181
* 11.0
  11.0.1
  15.0
  15.0.1
  openjdk64-11.0.1
  openjdk64-15.0.1
  oracle64-1.8.0.161
  oracle64-1.8.0.181
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Found that you need to register the java-17 dist in jenv using command:

```
jenv add /usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

The path to `/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk` you may take from your brew installation logs (found on the line `sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk ...`) and just add `/Contents/Home`

Now, it works

```sh
> jenv local 17.0
> java -version                                                                                                                                     
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 17.0.1+1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 17.0.1+1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: just wanted to add that as of 05/04/2022, with the latest jdk being 18, the above command will add jdk18 to your jenv. If you specifically need jdk17 - do this: jenv add /usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Great thanks. On my Mac it was /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.16/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home for brew isntall java11

Comment: @RobertAlexander I don't recommend linking to the cellar - otherwise it'll break when you upgrade to a new version.

Comment: I see and what is the best/more correct way of handling this?

Comment: @RobertAlexander in your case (apple silicon) for homebrew installations, the "correct" way would be to `jenv add /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11` (see https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/239#discussioncomment-162802 and https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-should-i-install-homebrew-in-the-default-location)

Comment: Very informative, thanks a lot.